# Congrats Adrian on achieving Legendary

Tags: discussion

Many Congratulations to [@Adrian](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/2995/adrian-larson) achieving Legendary badge

Comment: Thank you thank you!

Comment: Congrats @AdrianLarson

Comment: Congratulations!

Answer (score 25):

Many thanks to those of you who have asked such great questions throughout my years here. I have learned a great deal just from reading these questions, let alone the thought and experimentation they provoke. It seems to me the key to success both here and as a Salesforce developer is not so much knowing how to do everything, but rather knowing how to *learn* anything which is required.

I still remember thinking the [Mortarboard](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/badges/41/mortarboard) badge was nigh impossible. I couldn't possibly list out everyone who inspired me to be a bigger contributor here, and don't want to offend anyone by leaving them out, but just know that as a community many of you have inspired me with your tenor, thoughtfulness, and willingness to help. This place brings me joy, and I hope I am able to give a small part of that back.

Just for kicks and grins, here's a haiku to commemorate the occasion:

```
Want to help others?
So many internet points!
Salesforce Stack Exchange
```

Comment: so when is the party? I'll get the limo ready and bring the Pappy 23yr

Comment: Congrats Adrian!

Comment: Did somebody say Pappy?

Comment: Congratulations @Adrian. I've learnt a lot from your answers. Specially from your comments :p